# nextLong() not being read with use of delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I seem to struggle with scanner when it's reading from an input file. I'm still learning the ropes of java and I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

My main method is suppose to read an input file and depending on the first letter of the next line it would make either a song object or a image object which is then added to an array of type supper class. Here is part of my code for reading the input file:

```
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        in.useDelimiter(":");
        fileType = in.next().trim();
            if(fileType.equals("S")) {
                fileName = in.next().trim();
                artistName = in.next().trim();
                albumName = in.next();
                fileSize = in.nextLong(); //when it gets to this line, it gives a InputMisMatchException

                Song newSong = new Song(fileName, fileSize, artistName, albumName);
                mediaArray.add(newSong);
            }
```

Comment: Try `fileSize = Long.parseLong(in.next().trim())` because of the remaining spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to add `\n` in the delimiter, because if not it'll, with the number, until the next `:` which is next line
2. Then to handle the extra spaces around the number, here are 2 options :

   1. Use the delimiter  `"[:\\n]"` and `Long.parseLong(in.next().trim())` : you'll read spaces but remove them before parse
   2. Use the delimiter `"\s*:\s*|\n"` and keep `in.nextLong()` : you'll not read the spaces and directly be able to read a `double`

Comment: Thank you! The second optioned work perfectly. This is something I have not learned yet so I will definitely look into it

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your problems lies in changing the delimiter to:

```
"\\s*:\\s*|\n"
```

If you try out this example below it will not throw an exception on `in.nextLong()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String example = "S : Pink Bullets.mp3:  The Shins       :Chutes Too Narrow  :  105276041\n" +
            " I : CatamaranCruise#2.JPG   :  462   :  2010   :  33921\n" +
            " S : 16 Military Wives.mp3: The Decemberists        :Picaresque  : 431760781\n" +
            " S : Saint Simon.mp3:   The Shins       :Chutes Too Narrow  :  349515394\n" +
            " S : Sweet Disposition.mp3: The Temper Trap         :Conditions  :  45810162\n" +
            " I : CyberPatriotRound3.JPG   :  752   :  2011   :  25518\n" +
            " I : 15192479739_d343588b32_o.jpg   :  1652   :  2014   :  250959";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(example).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\n");
    String fileType;
    String fileName;
    String artistName;
    String albumName;
    long fileSize;
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        fileType = in.next().trim();
        if (fileType.equals("S")) {
            fileName = in.next().trim();
            artistName = in.next().trim();
            albumName = in.next();
            fileSize = in.nextLong(); //when it gets to this line, it gives a InputMisMatchException
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this work with this delimiter? This delimiter "removes" spaces from the extracted tokens, hence it removes spaces around the tokens which are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be to use regex for the whole thing. I'm aware that might not be what you asked for, but just an idea. Also might be out of your comfort zone.

A regex looking something like:

```
"S: *(.*?) *: *(.*?) *: *(.*?) *: *(\d+) *"
```

If match then just extract the capture groups.